# When are API levels marked as obsolete in the Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager, android-api-levels

I noticed that within the Android SDK Manager, it appears that most API levels below 15 are marked as obsolete (including [API level 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353503/why-is-android-api-level-9-obsolete)). But then I saw that API levels 8 and 10 are *not* marked as obsolete.

Why is that? And when will an Android API level be marked as obsolete?

PS: The [documentation of API levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) does not mention obsoleteness of API levels.

Comment: Think of it as a service pack. API 9 (2.3.0-2.3.2) was superseded by API 10 (Android 2.3.3-2.3.7) and since it was easy to adopt the small changes by manufacturers virtually no devices use API 9 in favor of API 10. Similarly for API 14 and 15.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your link, API (5,6) has been replaced with API (7) ECLAIR_MR1, API(9) has been replaced with API (10) GINGERBREAD_MR1 and API(11,12) has been replaced with API(13) HONEYCOMB_MR2 so you will find (5,6,9,11,12) will be absolute.
And level 8,10 are not obsolete because there is not a similar API level to replace it.

Comment: What does 'replaced' exactly mean in this context?

Comment: I mean that when APIs upgraded on the same os vesion the old ones will be obsolete otherwise it will not be.